# Searching for rows in ListView in xaml and c#

Tags: c#, xaml

The search by lines does not work, it does not give errors, I enter the text in the TextBox, when you click on the button, no actions occur, in what way you can implement a search by lines?
I attach the code:

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.UserPageWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
     mc:Ignorable="d"
      xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"

    Title="Приложение для пользователей" Height="591.134" Width="796.366">

<Grid Background="#D7D7D8" Margin="0,0,3.6,-0.4">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TabControl Grid.Row="0" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTabItem}">
        <TabItem Name="UsersTab">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Сотрудники"/>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <ListView x:Name="ViewAllUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding AllUsers}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}">
                <ScrollViewer>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ListView x:Name="listOfUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding AllPositions}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPosition}">
                            <ListView.View>
                                <GridView>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Имя"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Фамилия"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Famil}"/>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Отчество"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Otches}"/>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Должность"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Dolzhnost}"/>
                                    <GridViewColumn Header="Дата рождения"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Data_rozhde}"/>
                                </GridView>
                            </ListView.View>
                        </ListView>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ListView>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="PositionsTab">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Должности"/>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <TabItem.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Редактировать" Command="{Binding OpenEditItemWnd}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Удалить" Command="{Binding DeleteItem}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TabItem.ContextMenu>
            <ListView x:Name="ViewAllPositions" ItemsSource="{Binding AllPositions}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPosition}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Salary"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Salary}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Count of staffs"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PositionUsers.Count}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Max number"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=MaxNumber}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Department"
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PositionDepartment.Name}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Name="Depatrments">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <TextBlock Text="Отделы"/>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <TabItem.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="Редактировать" Command="{Binding OpenEditItemWnd}"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Удалить" Command="{Binding DeleteItem}"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TabItem.ContextMenu>
            <ListView x:Name="ViewAllDepartments" ItemsSource="{Binding AllDepartments}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDepartment}">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Name" 
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Count of positions" 
                                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=DepartmentPositions.Count}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">            
        <TextBox x:Name="nameFilter" Margin="100,15,15,13" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="186" >
            <TextBox.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1" ScaleX="-1"/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-179.74"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </TextBox.RenderTransform>
        </TextBox>
        <Button Click="ActiveFilter" Content="Применить фильтр" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        <Button x:Name="Button_Add"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Добавить" Click="Button_Add_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button_Ed"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Редактировать" Click="Button_Ed_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button_Del"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Удалить" Click="Button_Del_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="Button_Close"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" Content="Закрыть" Click="Button_Close_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

С#

```
public void ActiveFilter(List<AppStaff> AppStaffs)
    {
        listOfUsers.Items.Clear(); // очищаем лист с элементами

        for (int i = 0; i < AppStaffs.Count; i++) // перебираем элементы
        {
            listOfUsers.Items.Add(AppStaffs[i]); // добавляем элементы в ListBox
        }


    }
```

the list itself is output from the database, and it is filled in, and output to the ListView. Thank you
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qltMA.jpg)

for example, I enter a name (highlighted in red), click on the button and it should output or highlight a line, but it is not looking for

Comment: Could you post the relevant part of your viemodel (type of AllPositions, definition of AppStaff) and how the filter should work?

Comment: @Steeeve i add info

Comment: if `ÀctiveFilter` is an eventhandler of `Button.Click` (and triggers the search) it needs the signature of a `RoutedEventHandler`, i.e. `void ActiveFilter(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`

Comment: Also your XAML seems odd, at least to me.
You have a ListView 'ViewAllUsers' that contains a Stackpanel and a Scrollviewer and finally another ListView 'listOfUsers'.
A XAML ListView (at least in WPF) usually contains a GridView as its View (or custom View)...
The other ListViews use a GridView as their view.
Maybe the xaml for ViewAllUsers and listOfUsers got mixed up...

Comment: @lidqy  I'm a newbie

Comment: Hi @EdwardKamalov :), Didn't mean to bother and no pun intended. 
Just noticed, the XAML of Users-ListView could be optimized and also the signature of that ActiveFilter function. Maybe you have an overload or code isn't 1:1...